# Public subs don't work in this scenario

Tags: vb.net

I have a form named `FrmDrvouchers`. It contains some public subprocedures.
I call these subs from another form which opens from a form which is opened from FrmDrVouchers as a dialog.

When I open FrmDrvouchers directly, everything works. But when I call FrmDrvouchers from another project which is also part of this solution, its public subs don't work when I call them from another (dialog) form.

Here is the code of the Button Click from which I open FrmDrvouchers:

```
Dim FrmDrv As FrmDrVouchers = New FrmDrVouchers()    
FrmDrv.Show()
```

This works, but those public subs don't. Why?

---

Thanks For ur response,

It just skip what i want to do, but not throws any Exceptions,
Now I m posting my Code,,, plz have a look on that,,

Here is my Main form's MenuStrip Button Click code :

```
 Private Sub CashPaymentToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CashPaymentToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim DrVouchers As Transactions.FrmDebitVouchers = Transactions.New FrmDebitVouchers()
    DrVouchers.Show()
End Sub
```

---

Here is the FrmDebitVouchers's Public Subs which are not working,,, in the sense that they skip the function which i have written but not throwing any Exception,,

```
Public Sub DrVoucherOPen(ByVal VoucherNo As Integer)

    'Filling the Dataset with selected Voucher No to OPen the record
    DebitVouchersTableAdapter.FillByVoucher(Flr12131DataSet.DebitVouchers, VoucherNo)
    VoucherDateDateTimePicker.Enabled = False
End Sub

Public Sub DrVoucherBodyOPen(ByVal VoucherNo As Integer)

    '---------Procedure to Open DrVouchersBody And to OPen it in Datagridview-------------'
    'Getting the User No, and if it is admin then load fill dataset and allow user to edit the record
    If GetUserNumber() = 1 Then
        'Filling the dataset
        DebitVouchersBodyTableAdapter.FillByVoucher(Flr12131DataSet.DebitVouchersBody, VoucherNo)

        DrBodyDGV.DataSource = Nothing
        Dim Sum As New Decimal

        'Initializing the SerialNumbers variable
        SerialNumbers = New List(Of Integer)

        'Setting datagridview to opend record
        For i = 0 To Flr12131DataSet.DebitVouchersBody.Rows.Count - 1

            DrBodyDGV.Rows.Add()
            DrBodyDGV.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = Flr12131DataSet.DebitVouchersBody.Rows(i).Item("SerialNo")
            DrBodyDGV.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value = Flr12131DataSet.DebitVouchersBody.Rows(i).Item("AccountNo")
            DrBodyDGV.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value = Flr12131DataSet.DebitVouchersBody.Rows(i).Item("Debit")
            DrBodyDGV.Rows(i).Cells(7).Value = Flr12131DataSet.DebitVouchersBody.Rows(i).Item("Narration")
            'Getting serial No into List
            SerialNumbers.Add(Flr12131DataSet.DebitVouchersBody.Rows(i).Item("SerialNo"))

            'Getting Account Name into Datagridview
            If Not Not IsNumeric(DrBodyDGV.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value) Then
                Dim Qa As New Flr12131DataSetTableAdapters.QueriesTableAdapter
                Dim StrAccountName = Qa.GetAccountName(DrBodyDGV.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value)
                DrBodyDGV.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value = StrAccountName

            Else
            End If

            Sum += DrBodyDGV.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value

        Next


        TxtTotal.Text = Sum

        'Setting the controls properties for admin

        DrBodyDGV.AllowUserToAddRows = True
        DrBodyDGV.AllowUserToDeleteRows = True

        DrBodyDGV.ReadOnly = False
        BtnSave.Enabled = True
        BtnDelete.Enabled = True
        BtnPrint.Enabled = True
        ToUpdate = True
    Else


        'If user is not admin then load all record and not allow user to modify it or delete
        ' Bounding the datagridview

        Dim Sum As Decimal = 0
        BtnSave.Enabled = False
        DebitVouchersBodyTableAdapter.FillByVoucher(Flr12131DataSet.DebitVouchersBody, VoucherNo)
        DrBodyDGV.DataSource = Flr12131DataSet.DebitVouchersBody

        For i = 0 To DrBodyDGV.Rows.Count - 1
            If Not Not IsNumeric(DrBodyDGV.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value) Then
                Dim Qa As New Flr12131DataSetTableAdapters.QueriesTableAdapter
                Dim StrAccountName = Qa.GetAccountName(DrBodyDGV.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value)
                DrBodyDGV.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value = StrAccountName
            Else
            End If

            Sum += DrBodyDGV.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value

        Next

        TxtTotal.Text = Sum

        DrBodyDGV.AllowUserToAddRows = False
        DrBodyDGV.AllowUserToDeleteRows = False
        ' DrBodyDGV.edit()
        DrBodyDGV.ReadOnly = True
        BtnSave.Enabled = False
        BtnDelete.Enabled = False
        BtnPrint.Enabled = True

    End If


End Sub
```

---

Here is another the DrVouchersRecord form from which I call Public Subs:

```
Private Sub DrVouchersRecordDataGridView_CellDoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DrVouchersRecordDataGridView.CellDoubleClick


Dim FrmDrVouchers As FrmDebitVouchers = New FrmDebitVouchers()

    If FrmDrVouchers.DrBodyDGV.Rows.Count > 1 Then

        Dim Ans As Integer
        Ans = MsgBox("Unsaved changes will be lost, want to proceed", vbYesNo + vbInformation, "Alert")
        If Ans = vbYes Then
            Dim VoucherNo As New Integer

            VoucherNo = DrVouchersRecordDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value


            FrmDrVouchers.DrVoucherOPen(VoucherNo)
            FrmDrVouchers.DrVoucherBodyOPen(VoucherNo)
            Me.Close()
        End If

    Else

        Dim VoucherNo As New Integer

        VoucherNo = DrVouchersRecordDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value

        FrmDrVouchers.DrVoucherOPen(VoucherNo)
        FrmDrVouchers.DrVoucherBodyOPen(VoucherNo)
        Me.Close()

    End If
```

### End Sub

My forms sequence is:

FrmMain is my main startUp form

After that FrmDebitVouchers Open on menustripButtonclick

After that DebitVouchersRecord is Open as Dialog from DrmDebitVouchers,,, and from these Public Subs are called

I Have added Refrence also

Waiting for ur answers,

Comment: Can you show your code?  Without seeing it, it's impossible to tell you why "it's not working".

Comment: Yes. Please show one of the public subs that doesn't work and the code that tries to call it. Also, what about it doesn't work?  Does it just skip doing what you expect it to do, or does it throw an exception, or does it fail to compile?

Comment: make sure your have a project reference to be able to call methods in the other project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has hit many programmers coming from VB6 to VB.NET.

In your DataGridView_DoubleCellClick event you create a NEW instance of **FrmDebitVouchers**.
Then your code refers to property/methods/objects of this new INSTANCE, not of the original one created via CashPaymentToolStripMenuItem_Click. (Also note that this new instance is never showed on the screen, so you are sending/requesting changes to an hidden form instance)

Of course, the **DrBodyDGV.Rows.Count** is zero on this INSTANCE (referenced as FrmDrVouchers) because probably this INSTANCE has never been intialized like the first one.

Try to add a FrmDrVouchers.Show() after the creation and you will see the hidden SECOND INSTANCE of the form class FrmDebitVouchers.

To solve your problem, you need to pass the reference of the first FrmDebitVouchers instance to the DrVouchersRecord form (for example in the constructor or via a public property) and then use that reference instead of creating FrmDrVouchers

Comment: I'm glad that works, but you should really post the code of DataGridView_DoubleCellClick as before ( as part of the question ) because, without it, my response is incomprensible to other readers.

Comment: @Malik, see how the upvote on the first comment goes up? Please, post that piece of code that was in your deleted answer.

Comment: Here I have another problem,, Actually FrmDebitVouchers is already open,, and it has a button, which opens another dialog form(DrVouchersRecord) which have all Debit Vouchers Record Which are saved,,, And its datagridview Cell Click Event Run the Subs in FrmDebitVouchers,,,, Now problem is, when I use ur technique,, it opens a copy of Already opened form with filled data but previous form remains Empty,,, plz tell me how to overcome this problem,,